# How to implement List view for iPhone and Cards view for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I already have UITableView (as List view) implemented under UITableViewController and auto-layout configured to support all screen sizes including iPad.

But now I need Cards(multiple columns) based screen layout for iPad alone.
The straight approach I see is to add a new storyboard for iPad with new UICollectionViewController and duplicate all the swift logic there.

Is there a better way to use both layouts within same ViewController.swift and use different storyboards based on finding iPhone/iPad at runtime?

What is the standard way to use List in iPhone and Cards(multiple columns) in iPad?

Comment: Too broad a question because only you know your design for "list" versus "card". But, in general, use a `UICollectionView` for both with a standard cell for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Days ago, I had the same problem and I decided use [Traits](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/)  to make a TableView on iPhone and CollectionView on iPad.

If you want, you can download my project example [here](https://github.com/DiegoQuimbo/Challenge_Rappi)

Comment: This is it. Using Traits. And your example is very helpful, Thank you!